# Combining Static Sites + Client Side Rendering (React, Gatsby)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, server-side-rendering, client-side-scripting

I want to build a web app with React.

When users visit the site, they will see a `Landing Page`, can go to a `Pricing Page`, an `About page`, a `Blog`. etc. They can also `Sign Up` or `Log in` and then there's the actual app. I would like render certain pages (`Landing,Pricing,About,Blog`) *statically*, but would like to leave everything behind the SignUp/Login-Wall *client-side rendered*.

(First, because it cannot be static, since this is dynamic content. And also, because I do not care about SEO here anyways, so a major reason for next.js falls away, since the app is behind a SignUp/Login Wall anyways.)

Questions: First of all: Does this make sense? And secondly: How could I implement something like this? I haven't found anything online! Is this unheard of? I would like to use `Gatsby.js` for my static content, but I am not sure how to bring the client-side-rendered bit into the mix. I have worked with `create-react-app` before, which does client-side-rendering, - but I am not sure how I would go about the implementation?

Comment: This makes sense. We have lot real world applications that use something similar to this. For development, my approach would be to run the static on a different port and reactjs in a different port. For production, you can make use of rules in `nginx or apache` to route different paths to different build directories and serve the respective file.

Comment: https://github.com/sw-yx/jamstack-hackathon-starter

Comment: Your question is a little bit broad for stackoverflow. But have a look at the above link and at the blog post https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2018-12-17-turning-the-static-dynamic/ for some ideas. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much @Panther & ksav

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will try to explain the process behind [jamstack-hackathon-starter](http://github.com/sw-yx/jamstack-hackathon-starter) (which [@ksav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5385381/ksav) commented).

It is a starter template for gatsby that allows you to save static pages in-
conjunction with dynamic pages (client-side react app) - a "Hybrid Gatbsy App".

**Manual Steps:**
1. Create a folder `src/app` which will contain your client-side react app.
2. Create a file in `src/pages` called `app.js`, with the following contents:

```
// I'm using create-react-app's structure
import App from '../app/src/App' // make sure this path corresponds to your path

export default App
```

3. Now install [gatsby-plugin-create-client-paths](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-create-client-paths/):
   `npm install --save gatsby-plugin-create-client-paths`
4. Configure it by adding it to `gatsby-config.js` like so:

```
 plugins: [
 {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-create-client-paths`,
      options: { prefixes: [`/app/*`] },
 },
 ...
```

5. This will result in everything within `/app` to only be rendered in the browser (ie client-side).
6. Go to your browser after building (`gatsby develop`) and check `/app`

Comment: perfect, thanks. does this make sense for bigger apps too, or not really?

Comment: @R.Kohlisch yes. I found this question because it seemed like the logical approach for a big project too (landing page + login protected app). It does seem to be quite slow to run `gatsby develop` though (I hope they fix it soon), but still, conceptually it does make sense.

Answer (score 0):

According to npmjs
The plugin gatsby-plugin-create-client-paths  is deprecated.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-plugin-create-client-paths

This plugin's functionality is now built-in to Gatsby.
Use the File System Route API: https://gatsby.dev/creating-client-only-routes.
This package will no longer receive updates.